# (Python) while / for loops used with custom tkinter causing rotated image to appear outside of GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am attempting to rotate an image of an arrow in my custom tkinter GUI window. The code initially works as expected, but after about 25-28 seconds the arrow pops off the GUI window and rotates in the top left corner of my laptop screen. I'm am not sure which part of my code is causing the arrow to pop off the window. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to both python and tkinter.

```
def start(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.timer).start()
    self.angle = 90
    self.t = 0
    while self.t < 60:
        angle_2 = randint(-90, 90)

        if -90 < angle_2 < 90 and self.angle > angle_2:
            for i in reversed(range(angle_2, (self.angle + 1))):
                arrow_lab = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image_arr.rotate(i, expand=True, center=(28.5, 126)))
                self.label_arr = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.wind2_main, text="", image=arrow_lab)
                self.label_arr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
                self.angle = angle_2
                self.label_arr.update()
                self.label_arr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
            time.sleep(0.2)



        if -90 < angle_2 < 90 and angle_2 > self.angle:
            for i in range(self.angle, (angle_2 + 1)):
                arrow_lab = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image_arr.rotate(i, expand=True, center=(28.5, 126)))
                self.label_arr = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.wind2_main, text="", image=arrow_lab)
                self.label_arr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
                self.angle = angle_2
                self.label_arr.update()
                self.label_arr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
            time.sleep(0.2)

        self.t += 1
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbD7S.png)

Comment: It may be an artifact of using threading. Tkinter and threading is not a very good combination. I can't imagine why you need threading for such a simple operation. Also, there really isn't a need to continue to create new labels and stack them on top of each other. You can create a single label and just swap out the image on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I got this to work by adding the following line of code under each occurrence of "for each i in range" self.label_arr.after(1, self.label_arr.destroy())

Comment: That's not doing what you think it's doing. That's immediately calling `self.label_arry.destroy()` and then passing the results to `after`.

Comment: I thought it would destroy/delete the previous occurrence of the label that is causing the glitch. How would I achieve what you're suggesting by swapping out the image? @BryanOakley

Comment: `self.label.configure(image=arrow_lab)`, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley. With your solution I was still having trouble on my laptop but when I move the code over the my raspberry pi it worked fine. To give you context my team and I are making a bike generator and as the user peddles were having the gauge move. We're about 80% of the way there. Thanks again!